# Is GPU accelerated Xorg server released

Tags: driver

we are working C# windows form application. The rendering of form and form navigation is very slow. I was reading about the speed improved X org server or graphic driver about to release in 2013. Is that released?. How can i install the same.

Best Regards,
Sheela

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2013, a slightly accelerated frame buffer driver was made default in Rasbian. There is still as far as I know no "proper" accelerated GPU driver. The recent Broadcom release makes it slightly more possible, but no one has done it yet.